# Array size for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning java right now.

I have a class.

```
public static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 8;  // initial array capacity
protected int capacity;  // current capacity of the array
protected int front;     // index of the front element
protected int rear;      // index of the rear element
protected int[] A;      // array deque

public ArrayDeque( )      
{
    A = new int[ INIT_CAPACITY ];
    capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;
    front = rear = 0;
}


public int size( )
     {
            int countSize = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            {
                if(A[i] != front && A[i] != rear)
                {
                    countSize++;
                }
        }
      // COMPLETE THIS METHOD

     // Hint: size can be computed from capacity, front and rear.

    return count;   // replace this line with your code
}
```

I am trying to finish the method size. Does this make sense? Also, are there any good tips to check if I am on the right track?

My question might be too naive, my apology if it is. I just don't have lots of knowledge of programming.

Thank you

Comment: That's nice. Java arrays have a fixed length. So you should probably use `A.length` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return count;
```

what is `count`? Do you mean `countSize`?

In either case your size method runs in O(N), if you had a million elements, you'd have to traverse the array a million times just to get the size. That isn't a good idea.

Instead, use the `capacity` private instance variable to denote the current size, like this:

```java
public int size() {
  return capacity;
}
```

and whenever you add an element, presumably in `add(int x)`, increment `capacity` like: `capacity++;`

and whenever you delete an element, presumably in a `remove(int x)` or `removeFirst()`/`removeLast()`, decrement `capacity` like: `capacity--;`

and finally start `capacity` at `0` like: `capacity = 0;` inside your constructor, `ArrayDeque()`.

Comment: Yea, it is my mistake. It should've been 'countSize'.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand what you mean. I thought I have to check each array index to find whether it is null or not to find the size of the array.

Comment: nope, i have written many `ArrayDeque`'s in my time and ive found that this always works! Feel free to upvote/accept if you understood what i meant/found my answer helpful!